# Modifying values of dictionary contained in a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I'm having problems modifying the value per key in python. I googled it but I can't find anything similar to what I'm working on. 
I don't know but this may be very easy for some of you. I actually just started programming in python recently so this is something new.

I know I can use Lists and dictionaries as value pair for keys in a dictionary but I can't find a way to modify the value of a nested dictionary.

If I have `myDictionary = {'key':currentValue}` and I want to modify it's value, I can simply `myDictionary[key] = newValue`

But If I have,

```
myDictionary = {'key1':{'aKey':value1} , 'key2':{'bKey':value2}, 'key3':{'cKey':value3 } }
```

**How do I modify the value of `'aKey'` ?**

**Are there any limit of the number of dictionaries I can nest in a dictionary?**

I'd appreciate any help. I'm still playing around with it's syntax. Some are very different compared to Java.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you looking to iterate to look for a key. Or do you know exactly what you want to edit? Because you can simply do `myDictionary['key1']['aKey'] = 'new_val'`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should do.

```
myDictionary["key1"]["aKey"] = newValue
```

Comment: this is really helpful. I managed to also fix my problem with list[] value by following the code syntax you provided. Thank you.

Comment: You are Welcome. @p3ace .